invisible objects in View Wireframe
In Blender software, as soon as I go to wireframe view, my objects become invisible. How can I solve this problem?
OS: Windows 11 Enterprise
CPU: ntel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz
Ram: 8.00 GB
VGA: radeon rx 580 series


Hello and welcome Ramin Ghasemi, you just have toggle X-Ray on the left of the Wireframe View. Have a good day.

as Fred says you need to switch to X-Ray (Alt Z) to see the whole wireframe, also, what does it give if you select the cube? its contour should turn orange
